# Strange ElementTree remove() behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.6

I've a strange issue using elementTree while trying to remove an element,
It's seem that it's just navigating and deleting only the odd elements.

Here is the code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('bug_remove.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for element in root:
    print element.tag

print "remove all"

for element in root:
    print "remove element : "+element.tag
    root.remove(element)

print "remaining elements"

for element in root:
    print element.tag
```

And the output :

```
element1
element2
element3
element4
element5
element6
=> remove all
remove element : element1
remove element : element3
remove element : element5
=> remaining elements
element2
element4
element6
```

The xml file parsed :

```
<root>
        <element1>
        </element1>
        <element2>
        </element2>
        <element3>
        </element3>
        <element4>
        </element4>
        <element5>
        </element5>
        <element6>
        </element6>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since deleting an element while iterating the same list generate issues,
The fix is to iterate throught a copy (root[:]) :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('bug_remove.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

print "XML length : ", len(root)

for element in root[:]:
    print "remove element : "+element.tag
    root.remove(element)

print "remaining elements"

for element in root:
    print element.tag
```

And the output :

```
 XML length :  6
 remove element : element1
 remove element : element2
 remove element : element3
 remove element : element4
 remove element : element5
 remove element : element6
 remaining elements
```

Might help someone who has the same issue